# No suitable constructor found for

Tags: java, javac

I am having issues with getting the TestPolygon.java to run correctly. THe "//Constructor that creates four polygons with any value that are not equal to the defualt value or to each other Polygon[] P_array = {new Polygon(10,5.0,1.0,3.0), new Polygon(6,3,2,5), new Polygon(4,11,4,3), new Polygon(5,12,6,7)}; " line of my code keeps coming back with an error for every new statement saying that "no suitable constructor found for Polygon(int,double,double,double). Picture is attached.

```
/* File: Polygon.java
* Author: Darren Pirtle Jr.
* Date: November 16, 2016
* Purpose: Design a Java class
* named Polygon
*/

import java.lang.Math;

public class Polygon {
 private int numSides;
 private double sideLength;
 private double xCoord;
 private double yCoord;
 private double apothem;
 private double perimeter;

 //Constructor that creates a Polygon using the defaults
 public Polygon(){
     numSides = 4;
     sideLength = 10.0;
     xCoord = 0.0;
     yCoord = 0.0;
     apothem = 5.0;
}
 //Constructor that uses the specified numbers
 public Polygon(int s,double sL,double x,double y,double a, double p){
     setNumSides(s);
     setSideLength(sL);
     setXCoord(x);
     setYCoord(y);
     setApothem(a);
}

 // A getArea() method that returns a double value for the area of the polygon
 public double getArea() {
 return .5*apothem*perimeter;
}

 // Getter and setter for all data fields
 public int setNumSides(int s){
      numSides = s;
      return numSides;
}
 public double setSideLength(double sL){
      sideLength = sL;
      return sideLength;
}
 public double setXCoord(double x){
      xCoord = x;
      return xCoord;
}
 public double setYCoord(double y){
      yCoord = y;
      return yCoord;
}
 public double setApothem(double a){
      apothem = a;
      return apothem;
}
 public double setPerimeter(double p){
       perimeter = p;
       return perimeter;
}
 public int getNumSides() {
 return numSides; 
 }
 public double getSideLength() { 
 return sideLength; 
 }
 public double getXCoord() { 
 return xCoord; 
 }
 public double getYCoord() {
 return yCoord; 
 }
 public double getApothem() {
 return apothem;
 }
 public double getPerimeter() {
 return perimeter;
 }

 //A toString() that displays the values in string format
 public String toString(){
      return "("+numSides+", "+String.format("%.1f",sideLength)+", "+String.format("%.1f",xCoord)+", "+String.format("%.1f",yCoord)+")";
 }
}
```

---

```
/* File: Polygon.java
* Author: Darren Pirtle Jr.
* Date: November 16, 2016
* Purpose: Design a Java class
* named Polygon
*/

//Import necessary packages
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.lang.Math;

class TestPolygon{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    //Constructor that creates one polygon with no argument
    Polygon P = new Polygon();

    //Constructor that creates four polygons with any value that are not equal to the defualt value or to each other
    Polygon[] P_array = {new Polygon(10,5.0,1.0,3.0), new Polygon(6,3,2,5), new Polygon(4,11,4,3), new Polygon(5,12,6,7)};

    //Constructor that calls all methods and displays results
    System.out.println("toString() results: "+P);
    System.out.println("getNumSides() results: "+ P.getNumSides());
    System.out.println("getSideLength() results: "+ P.getSideLength());
    System.out.println("getXCoord() results: "+ P.getXCoord());
    System.out.println("getYCoord() results: "+ P.getYCoord());
    System.out.println("getPerimeter() results: "+ P.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("setNumSides(4) results: "+ P.setNumSides(4));
    System.out.println("setSideLength(3.0) results: "+ P.setSideLength(3.0));
    System.out.println("setXCoord(2.0) results: "+ P.setXCoord(2));
    System.out.println("setYCoord(2.0) results: "+ P.setYCoord(2));
    for(int i=0; i<P_array.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("toString() results: "+P_array[i]);
    System.out.println("getNumSides() results: "+ P_array[i].getNumSides());
    System.out.println("getSideLength() results: "+ P_array[i].getSideLength());
    System.out.println("getXCoord() results: "+ P_array[i].getXCoord());
    System.out.println("getYCoord() results: "+ P_array[i].getYCoord());
    System.out.println("getPerimeter() results: "+ P_array[i].getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("setNumSides(4) results: "+ P_array[i].setNumSides(4));
    System.out.println("setSideLength(3.0) results: "+ P_array[i].setSideLength(3.0));
    System.out.println("setXCoord(2.0) results: "+ P_array[i].setXCoord(2));
    System.out.println("setYCoord(2.0) results: "+ P_array[i].setYCoord(2));
    }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqXKE.png)

Comment: The error message seems pretty obvious to me. Your Polygon() constructor accepts an int and 5 doubles. You are attempting to use a constructor that takes an int and _4_ doubles. A tiny bit of research probably would have gone a long way here.

Comment: Which constructor exactly are you trying to invoke with `new Polygon(10, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0)`? Compare its expected amount of arguments with amount of arguments you are actually providing. Do they match?

Comment: I did do research. The reason I posted on here is because I needed help because I didnt find anything. Thanks for the rude comment and help though!

Comment: It's actually an int and _3_ other values, for a total of 4.
You'll also want to fix your setters to be of type `void` and not return anything. Plus, *Java* and *JavaScript* are separate, unrelated languages.

Comment: Research includes googling the error message.

Comment: Thank all of you again. Sorry if this is a bad question but this is my first java programming class so I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling Polygon() with 4 arguments, but you do not have a 4 argument constructor. You have a no arg

```
 public Polygon(){
     numSides = 4;
     sideLength = 10.0;
     xCoord = 0.0;
     yCoord = 0.0;
     apothem = 5.0;
}
```

and 6 arg

```
public Polygon(int s,double sL,double x,double y,double a, double p){
 setNumSides(s);
 setSideLength(sL);
 setXCoord(x);
 setYCoord(y);
 setApothem(a);
}
```

but you are calling

```
new Polygon(10,5.0,1.0,3.0)
```

You can either add 2 arguments to your new Polygon calls OR remove 2 arguments from the 6 arg constructor OR create a constructor that takes 4 arguments.

Comment: The constructor has _6_ arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Counting is hard.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameterized constructor takes 6 arguments ,i.e,

- int s
- double sL
- double x
- double y
- double a
- double p

But, when you are constructing the polygon, you are passing in only four values, i.e 
`new Polygon(10,5.0,1.0,3.0)`

Since you are not using the last argument in your constructor, i.e "double p", your constructor should be : `public Polygon(int s,double sL,double x,double y,double a)`

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

> no suitable constructor found for Polygon(int,double,double,double).

It simply means that Java is unable to find a constructor for class Polygon with argument `(int, double, double, double)` (which is what you have used when creating a Polygon object)

If you look at your constructors for class Polygon:

You created 2 constructors:

- No arguments constructor
- Constructor with 6 arguments (int, double, double, double, double, double)

---

Hence, when creating a Polygon object, ensure you are doing:

```
new Polygon(); 
or
new Polygon(int, double, double, double, double, double);
```

**Example:**

```
Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
Polygon p2 = new Polygon(10, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5);
Polygon p3 = new Polygon(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);    //this is ok too
```

**Right now, you are providing only 4 arguments:**

```
new Polygon(10, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0), 
             ^   ^    ^    ^
             |   |    |    |
            int  d    d    d  (d for double)
```